# Running compiled fortran as an .exe on remote web hosting

Tags: javascript, php, windows, fortran, web-hosting

This is somewhat of a general question but I'm happy to provide specifics...

I'm currently working on a project that involves building a form based web interface for a program that calculates food requirements of animals based on environmental inputs and returns the output back to the web page for display.

What I'm struggling with is that the 'back end' code (the code that does the complex calculations) is written in Fortran (which can then be compiled to a .exe file). I've found methods in PHP to execute exe files using a dynamically generated csv as an input but I'm wondering if there are remote web hosts that allow this kind of command line functionality. Any advice?

As a last resort we would set up our own web server but we would love to find a long term solution that uses 3rd party hosting.

I'm also open to better ways of doing this...thanks!

Comment: So are you looking for a hosting (completely off-topic), or finding a solution to run the exe in a particular environment? Which environment, Windows Server? Do you know CGI http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface ?

Comment: I think this belongs to http://serverfault.com/ but I will wait with my vote to move.

Comment: I guess both! This is one of those cases where I don't know where to start. I wrote a php script that generates inputs for a Fortran program that was written by someone else. The fortran program can then be compiled to an .exe file which I'm assuming can only run on a windows server. I'm basically looking for a solution to run this .exe file once the input file is generated but I'm not sure where to start. Sorry if this is the wrong place to post this. I'm guessing it's hard to find web hosts that will allow you to run exe files for security reasons...